# Making a login method in Xamarin.forms

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Once the user submits the login info, and presses login button the following method is called;

```cs
public Page OnLogInButtonClicked (string email, string password)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://babyAPI.com");
    var request = 
        new RestRequest("api/ApiKey?email=" + email + "&password=" + password, Method.GET);

    var queryResult = client.Execute(request);

    if (queryResult.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
        var x = deserial.Deserialize<ApiKey>(queryResult);

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? And if the user is authenticated, I need to navigate to a new page, else show authentication failed. How can that be done?

Comment: looks good. What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad. What are you looking to solve?

Here's what I think can be improved in this code. Assuming this is a ViewModel class - if it isn't read up on [MVVM](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) in [Xamarin](http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-xamarin-forms-labs-xaml-mvvm-ioc/). I'd suggest also reading up on [Separation of Concerns](http://deviq.com/separation-of-concerns/) (also see the links on the bottom about DRY and Single Responsibility)

```
// make the method async so your UI doesn't lock up
public async Task AuthenticateAndNavigate(string email, string pass){
  // your MVVM framework may have IsBusy property, otherwise - define it
  // it should be bindable so you can use it to bind activity indicators' IsVisible and buttons' IsEnabled 
  IsBusy = true; 
  try{
    // split out the code that talks to the server in a separate class - don't mix UI, ViewModel and server interactivity (separation of concerns principle)
    // the assumption here is that a null is returned if auth fails
    var apiKey = BabyApi.GetApiKey(email, pass);

    // the Navigation property below exists in some MVVM frameworks, otherwise it comes from a Page instance that calls this code
    if (apiKey!=null) 
      await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage());
    else 
      await Navigation.PushAsync(new FailedToAuthenticatePage()); // or just do nothing
  } catch { 
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new FailedToAuthenticatePage { Error: x.Message });
  } finally {
    IsBusy = false;
  }
}
```